# SQL Server: update binary data from jpeg files for mutiple jpeg files

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `guest` with two columns:

- IMAGE  datatype varchar(50) - contains a jpeg file path
- IMG  datatype image

I need to update all the records for `IMG` column to binary data which is present in the location mentioned in the `IMAGE` column.

```
UPDATE guest 
SET img = (SELECT bulkcolumn 
           FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\Webcam Images\24092018071230.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X) 
WHERE ID = 53
```

This SQL statement will update only one single record at a time. But I need to update all records corresponding to jpeg file for each record to `Image` datatype column `IMG`.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to directly test this code, but something like this should work (you could also rewrite as a cursor, add error checking, etc.):

```
create table #guest (
    ID int,
    FilePath varchar(50),
    FileImage image,
    Updated tinyint
)

insert into #guest (ID, FilePath, FileImage, Updated)
    select ID, Image, IMG, 0
    from guest

declare @sql varchar(1500), @FilePath varchar(50), @ID int

while exists (select top 1 ID from #guest where Updated = 0)
begin

    select top 1 @ID = ID, @FilePath = FilePath from #guest where Updated = 0

    select @sql = 'update #guest set FileImage = ' + '(select bulkcolumn from openrowset(bulk n''' + @FilePath + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X) where ID = ' + @ID

    exec sp_executesql @sql

    update #guest set Updated = 1 where ID = @ID

end

update g
set g.IMG = #guest.FileImage
from guest g
inner join #guest on g.ID = #guest.ID
```

Comment: Instead of using while loop. is there a single sql update command to perform this task.